# keras CNN same output

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, convolution

I have trained a **CNN** neural network in **python** with 800 samples and tested it on 60. The output accuracy is 50 and now every time I use model.**predict** it gives me the **same result**.

```
#main file - run this to train the network

import numpy as np
from keras.datasets import cifar10
from datasetFetch import DataFetch
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.constraints import maxnorm
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D
from keras.layers.convolutional import MaxPooling2D
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras import backend as K
K.set_image_dim_ordering('th')
import simplejson
from matplotlib import pyplot
from scipy.misc import toimage
# load data
#(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = cifar10.load_data()
# create a grid of 3x3 images
#for i in range(0, 9):
#   pyplot.subplot(3,3,1 + i)
#   pyplot.imshow(toimage(X_train[i]))
# show the plot
#pyplot.show()

#init data
CONST_PHOTOS = 400 # number of photos of each type
y_train = []

#train data
data = DataFetch('orange',CONST_PHOTOS)
data1 = data.openPictures()
data = DataFetch('apple', CONST_PHOTOS)
data.removeErrorImages()
data2 = data.openPictures()

#test data
tdata = DataFetch('test-orange',30)
tdata1 = tdata.openPictures()
tdata = DataFetch('test-apple',30)
tdata2 = tdata.openPictures()

#add togheter data
X_train = data.connectData(data1,data2,'train')
y_train = data.getYtrain('train')
X_test = tdata.connectData(tdata1,tdata2,'test')
y_test = tdata.getYtrain('test')

# fix random seed for reproducibility
seed = 7
np.random.seed(seed)

# normalize inputs from 0-255 to 0.0-1.0
X_train = X_train.astype('float32')
X_test = X_test.astype('float32')
X_train = X_train / 255.0
X_test = X_test / 255.0

#one hot encode outputs
y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train)
y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test)
num_classes = y_train.shape[1] #number of categories


# Create the model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(224, (11, 11), input_shape=(224, 224, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Conv2D(55, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), data_format="channels_last"))
model.add(Conv2D(13, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Conv2D(13, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), data_format="channels_last"))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu', kernel_constraint=maxnorm(3)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

# Compile model
epochs = 100
lrate = 0.01
decay = lrate/epochs
sgd = SGD(lr=lrate, momentum=0.9, decay=decay, nesterov=False)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy'])
#print(model.summary())
model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), epochs=epochs, batch_size=10)

# Final evaluation of the model
scores = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print("Accuracy: %.2f%%" % (scores[1]*100))

#and then we save
# serialize model to JSON
model_json = model.to_json()
with open("Data/model.json", "w") as json_file:
    json_file.write(simplejson.dumps(simplejson.loads(model_json), indent=4))
# serialize weights to HDF5
model.save_weights("Data/model.h5")
print("Saved model to disk")
```

I used **keras** and **tensorflow**. Images are **224x224** pixels each split in 2 categories. I don't know very much about neural network, this being my first attempt to making one this big work. I heard it might be over fitting or maybe I need one more important layer, or maybe my batch-size/epochs/learn rate is wrong.

## Any help is appreciated!

Edit1: How is the seed affecting the training of the network?
After training the accuracy is exactly 50% and by using a separate .py file which only loads the model and uses predict function on it returns the exact output percentage for any image I use. I tried with both images used for training and external ones.
I added the dataFetch code.

```
    #preparing the photos to be 224x224 and getting them from urls saved in txt files

from PIL import Image
import requests
from io import BytesIO
import numpy as np
import socket
import random
from scipy import misc
from PIL import ImageChops
import math, operator
from functools import reduce
import glob
import os
import signal

compare = Image.open('/home/mihai/PycharmProjects/neuralnet/compare.jpg')
compare1 = Image.open('/home/mihai/PycharmProjects/neuralnet/compare1.jpg')
compare2 = Image.open('/home/mihai/PycharmProjects/neuralnet/compare2.jpg')
compare3 = Image.open('/home/mihai/PycharmProjects/neuralnet/compare3.jpg')
compare4 = Image.open('/home/mihai/PycharmProjects/neuralnet/compare4.jpg')

def rmsdiff(im1, im2):
    "Calculate the root-mean-square difference between two images"

    h = ImageChops.difference(im1, im2).histogram()

    # calculate rms
    return math.sqrt(reduce(operator.add, map(lambda h, i: h*(i**2), h, range(256))) / (float(im1.size[0]) * im1.size[1]))

class DataFetch:

    chosenFile = ''
    maxNumber = 0
    y_train = []
    y_test = []

    def __init__(self, choice, number):
        print('Images with '+choice+'s are being prepared')
        self.chosenFile = choice
        self.maxNumber = number

    def getPictures(self):
        imgArr = np.zeros((self.maxNumber, 224, 224, 3), dtype='uint8')
        count = 0
        class timeoutError(Exception):
            signal.alarm(0)
        def handler(signum, frame):
            raise timeoutError
        with open(self.chosenFile, "r") as ins:
            for line in ins:
                if count < self.maxNumber:
                    signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, handler)
                    signal.alarm(3)
                    try:
                        try:
                            r = requests.get(line)
                            try:
                                img = Image.open(BytesIO(r.content))
                                ok = 0
                                try:
                                    if rmsdiff(compare, img) > 1.3 and rmsdiff(compare1, img) > 1.3 and rmsdiff(compare2, img) > 1.3 and rmsdiff(compare3, img) > 1.3 and rmsdiff(compare4, img) > 1.3:
                                        ok = 1
                                    else:
                                        print('Image removed from website')
                                except ValueError:
                                    ok = 1
                                if ok == 1:
                                    img = img.resize((224, 224))
                                    img = img.convert('RGB')
                                    img.save('/home/mihai/PycharmProjects/neuralnet/images/'+self.chosenFile+'/'+str(count)+".jpg", 'JPEG')
                                    imgArr[count, :, :, :] = img
                                    count = count + 1
                                    print(count)
                            except OSError:
                                print('Image not Available')
                        except socket.error:
                            print('URL not available')
                    except timeoutError:
                        print("URL not available")
        return imgArr

    def openPictures(self):
        cdir = os.getcwd()
        imgArr = np.zeros((self.maxNumber, 224, 224, 3), dtype='uint8')
        count = 0
        for filename in glob.glob(cdir+'/images/'+self.chosenFile+'/*.jpg'):
            if count < self.maxNumber:
                img = Image.open(filename)
                imgArr[count, :, :, :] = img
                count = count + 1
        return imgArr

    def removeErrorImages(self):
        cdir = os.getcwd()
        for filename in glob.glob(cdir+'/images/'+self.chosenFile+'/*.jpg'):
            img = Image.open(filename)
            try:
                if rmsdiff(compare, img) < 1.3 or rmsdiff(compare1, img) < 1.3 or rmsdiff(compare2, img) < 1.3 or rmsdiff(compare3, img) < 1.3 or rmsdiff(compare4, img) < 1.3:
                    os.remove(cdir+'/images/'+self.chosenFile+'/'+filename+'.jpg')
            except ValueError:
                pass

    def getYtrain(self,outParam):
        if outParam == 'train':
            self.y_train = np.reshape(self.y_train, (len(self.y_train), 1))
            return self.y_train
        else:
            self.y_test = np.reshape(self.y_test, (len(self.y_test), 1))
            return self.y_test

    def connectData(self, data1, data2, outParam):
        d1c = 0
        d2c = 0
        outList = []
        X_train = np.zeros((2 * self.maxNumber, 224, 224, 3), dtype='uint8')
        for i in range(2 * self.maxNumber):
            if d1c < self.maxNumber and d2c <self.maxNumber:
                if random.random() <= 0.5:
                    X_train[d1c + d2c, :, :, :] = data1[d1c, :, :, :]
                    d1c = d1c + 1
                    outList.append(0)
                else:
                    X_train[d1c + d2c, :, :, :] = data2[d2c, :, :, :]
                    d2c = d2c + 1
                    outList.append(1)
            else:
                if d1c < self.maxNumber:
                    X_train[d1c + d2c, :, :, :] = data1[d1c, :, :, :]
                    d1c = d1c + 1
                    outList.append(0)
                else:
                    if d2c < self.maxNumber:
                        X_train[d1c + d2c, :, :, :] = data2[d2c, :, :, :]
                        d2c = d2c + 1
                        outList.append(1)
        if outParam == 'train':
            self.y_train = outList
        else:
            if outParam == 'test':
                self.y_test = outList
        return X_train
```

Code for predict:

```
#run this to test a sample

from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras.models import model_from_json
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from datasetFetch import DataFetch

# load json and create model
json_file = open('Data/model2.json', 'r')
loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
json_file.close()
loaded_model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)

# load weights into new model
loaded_model.load_weights("Data/model2.h5")
print("Loaded model from disk")

epochs = 100
lrate = 0.01
decay = lrate/epochs
sgd = SGD(lr=lrate, momentum=0.9, decay=decay, nesterov=False)
loaded_model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy'])

#prepare X_test
tdata = DataFetch('test-orange',int(3))
tdata1 = tdata.openPictures()
tdata = DataFetch('test-apple',int(3))
tdata2 = tdata.openPictures()
X_test = tdata.connectData(tdata1,tdata2,'test')
y_test = tdata.getYtrain('test')
X_test = X_test.astype('float32')
X_test = X_test / 255.0
y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test)
print('Number of samples to be tested: '+str(X_test.shape[0]))

scores = loaded_model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print(scores[1]*100)

score = loaded_model.predict(X_test,batch_size=6, verbose=1)
print(score) #prints percentages
```

Comment: The accuracy is the same because you set a fixed random seed

Comment: What do you mean by "it gives the same result"? It makes the same prediction whatever input you pass to it, or you pass it the same input and it always gets 50% accuracy?

Comment: ah sorry, I thought you used model.predict in the same script. What is the accuracy/loss of the model in the training phase? and how do reload your data and model before using model predict?

Comment: I would first look for problems in DataFetch. Where's the code?

Comment: Can you first confirm that you are actually getting different images and labels are correct? In other words, that the DataFetch works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

The image preparation was correct. The problem was in the structure of the neural net plus the optimization method used.

Because of the huge number of neurons used for classifying just 2 classes, the structure was over fitting, causing the accuracy to stick at 50%.

The second problem was with the sgd optimizer. I instead used:

```
opt=keras.optimizers.rmsprop(lr=0.0001, decay=1e-6)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy']
```

**Hope this helps others as well!**